# Trigger a Timer once player enters an object and stops when it enters another

Tags: unity-game-engine

I currently have this code attached to a player to start a timer that ends when I enter a trigger, but I want to make it start when I enter a trigger rather than when I start my game.

```c#
public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text timerText;
    private float startTime;
    private bool finished = false;
    private bool started = false;


    void Update()
    {
        if (finished)
            return;

        if (started)
        { 
            float t = Time.time - startTime;

            string minutes = ((int)t / 60).ToString();
            string seconds = (t % 60).ToString("f2");

            timerText.text = minutes + ":" + seconds;
        }
    }

    public void Finish()
    {
        finished = true;
        timerText.color = Color.yellow;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        started = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the same thing you've done with the `bool finished`, but instead it would be something like `bool started`, which returns true when the player enters the start trigger. Wrap it around the time changing code inside your `Update()` statement.

Making sure the bools inside Timer are public:

```c#
public Text timerText;
public bool finished = false;
public bool started = false;

private float t = 0f;

void Update()
{
   if (finished)
      return;

   if (started) 
      t += Time.deltaTime;

   string minutes = ((int)t / 60).ToString();
   string seconds = (t % 60).ToString("f2");

   timerText.text = minutes + ":" + seconds;
}

void Started() 
{
    started = true;
}
```

And then inside a trigger script, reference your Timer attached to Player.

```c#
public class StartTrigger : MonoBehaviour 
{

    private GameObject player;
    private Timer timer;

    void Start() 
    {
        player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Ellen");
        if (player)
            timer = player.GetComponent<Timer>();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
    {
        if (other.tag == "Ellen") 
        {
            timer.Started();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my new code above, but the timer doesn't start at all when I have that.

Comment: @DerrickHenicke just to be sure, are you using [OnTriggerEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) to detect triggers?

Comment: Yes, I have this on my triggers:
public class FinishLine : MonoBehaviour {

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        GameObject.Find("Ellen").SendMessage("Finish");
    }
}

Comment: And your `bool finished` is working correctly? You are referencing the Timer script inside the triggers and changing finished to true?

Comment: Oh I see how you're doing it now, I didn't realise. It's fine though, there are many ways to do the same thing. Let me change my answer then.

Comment: If not started you should also return. Would be more efficient since doing the rest makes no sense when the timer isn't changing. Also `Find` and `SendMessage` are quite inefficient .. you should rather get the reference before hand (e.g. `FindObjectOfType<Timer>();` and use the method directly

Comment: I updated my code above to what I have now, and I do have the OnTriggerEnter set to that on the trigger objects as "Start" and "Finish". The timer still starts immediately when I load in still.

Comment: @derHugo I don't understand what you are meaning. Sorry.

Comment: @DerrickHenicke Don't use `Start` as method name! This is a name reserved for the Unity message called on start of the scene.

Comment: Yes, what derHugo said both times is correct. @DerrickHenicke he's saying you should reference the Timer script from the player, inside the trigger's scripts.

Comment: @DerrickHenicke I mean: change `if (started) 
      float t = Time.time - startTime;` to `if(!started) return; float t = Time.time - startTime;` and get the reference to the Timer before e.g. `public Timer _timer; private void Awake(){ _timer = FindObjectOfType<Timer>(); }` or reference it in the inspector and later only use `_timer.Started()` and `_timer.Finished()`

Comment: okay I changed from "Start" to "started", and now the timer text appears when I enter the start trigger and ends when I reach the other. BUT it is still counting from when my game loads. I can stand there for however long once it loads and then enter the start trigger, and the timer is already at 15 or however many seconds.

Comment: @DerrickHenicke The last part of my answer is showing you how you should reference the script first, to call functions more efficiently. As derHugo has pointed out. Assuming the player is tagged as "Ellen".

Comment: @DerrickHenicke initialize your float t out of the update function, and replace the one inside the update function with t += Time.deltaTime;

Comment: Okay, that corrected the timer issue and it is now running properly upon entering and exiting the triggers. I am still confused as to what you are saying about the timer scripts and trigger script. I have my timer script on my player, and each of triggers have the OnTrigger script attached to them.

Comment: @DerrickHenicke like derHugo said, using SendMessage to call a function in another script is more resource consuming than referencing it first, then calling it. If you look at the last part of my answer, I referenced player and Timer script in the Start() function of the trigger script, then called the function of the Timer script using timer.Started(). In the finish trigger, it would be timer.Finish() instead. Although, I would personally put OnTriggerEnters on the player and the trigger objects would have no scripts.